# C# images inside of a ListView

Tags: c#, image, listbox, fromfile

I want to make a ListView that has small images, that was taken from a scanner, inside of the ListView. (I have the scanning script done, and it saves the scanned image under C:/Temp/*****.jpg. )

What I'm having trouble with is, I want the scanned images to be displayed inside of the ListView and when you click an image in the ListView it displayed the full Image in the PictureBox.

[An Image of what i'm talking about.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6686544/Capture.jpg)(tried to post the image inside of this post but rep isn't high enough)

I was thinking about having the images' location stored inside of an List array like

```
List<string> fileLocationArray = new List<string>();
foreach () {
...
string fileLoc = (@"C:\temp\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss") + ".jpeg");
fileLocationArray.Add(fileLoc);
...
}
```

Then displaying the images inside the ListView using the List array.

Keep in mind that I plan on uploading these images to an FTP server. That's why I wanted to use a List array.

one more thing, they will be picture of document, not photos, if that means anything to you.

Comment: WPF or WinForms?  It really makes all the difference.

Comment: I would NOT use a listbox for that. I would use either a grid with only 1 column (the image column) or a listview with big icons and no text. in WPF you do have much more power and options than in Windows Forms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a ListBox of images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205531/creating-a-listbox-of-images)

Comment: Sorry, it was a miss type, It is a ListView and not ListBox (hope I corrected everything) And it's a Windows Form Application.

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to use ListView? (asking because your screenshot would make me suggest a ListBox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**Fill ListView :**   
 For(int i=0; i<fileLocationArray.Count();i++)
    {
    System.Windows.Controls.Image imgControl=new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    BitmapImage imgsrc = new BitmapImage();
   imgsrc.BeginInit();
   imgsrc.UriSource=fileLocationArray[i];
                    imgsrc.EndInit();
    imgControl.source=imgsrc;
    listView.Items.Add(imgControl);

    }

    **After filling ListView control  create event  listView SelectionChanged**
    **imgContolShow   // this control show selected image**

    void listw_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           imgContolShow.Source = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)listwiev.SelectedItem).Source;  
        }
```