# Create infinite sequence of Image

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I need to create a infinite sequence of images ex:

```
     string connectionLine;
                    connectionLine = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
                    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionLine);
                    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT comment_content, comment_author FROM " + wp_comments + " WHERE comment_post_ID =@iddo and comment_approved =@app";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("article", article.id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("app", "1");
                    MySqlDataReader Reader;
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        if (Reader.HasRows == true)
                        { 
                            while (Reader.Read())
                            {
                                radListControl1.Items.Add("By: " + Reader.GetValue(1) + " - " + Reader.GetValue(0));

                                PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
                                myPicBox.Location = new Point(300, 200);
                                myPicBox.Width = 328;
                                myPicBox.Height = 131;
                                myPicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                                myPicBox.Visible = true;
                                myPicBox.Image = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.fumetto);
                                this.Controls.Add(myPicBox);

                                PictureBox myPicBox1 = new PictureBox();
                                myPicBox1.Location = new Point(myPicBox.Location.X, myPicBox.Location.Y + 100);
                                myPicBox1.Width = 328;
                                myPicBox1.Height = 131;
                                myPicBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                                myPicBox1.Visible = true;
                                myPicBox1.Image = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.fumetto);
                                this.Controls.Add(myPicBox1);
                            }
   }
            }
            catch
            { }
```

but this mode is good for 2 or 3 element for more element it's impossibile to calculate distance of image.

My Idea is this:

[image]

it is possibile? how to create this infinite sequenze of image with space between images ?

Comment: I imagine your performance after awhile is going to be an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a ListBox of images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205531/creating-a-listbox-of-images)

Comment: no my questione is "creation loop of image" not listbox!

Comment: @Federal09 - What do you mean by "loop of image"?  A listBox is a user control.  A `while` loop is a programming construct.  Neither one has anything to do with the other.

Comment: And your sample output certainly looks like it could be implemented as a ListBox of images.

Comment: ah yes? Ok now you create a listbox with my example ok?? I wait your project on vs!

Comment: listbox with image and text http://postimg.org/image/w2tuqpign/

Comment: I was thinking that you would dynamically generate the entire row (username, photo, conversation text, and blue speech bubble) as one image per list item.

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this.

Comment: **Infinite** sequence is just such a very absolutely mind-boggingly hugely long sequence ..... can't you settle for one less than infinity? :-)